# My SASS loop is breaking using interpolation and percentage

Tags: css, sass

This code is breaking my SASS process for some reason..

```
@for $i from 1 through 100 {
  .t-#{$i} {
    top: #{$i}%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change to this:

```
@for $i from 1 through 100 {
  .t-#{$i} {
    top: 1% * $i
  }
}
```

From [SASS docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation):

[image: SASS]

Here is an [example](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/d0cf21d765ef50d947051ae48fdc4280)

Comment: Lovely stuff, that worked - thanks. How come % variables don't work here? 

Comment: @Adam see my updated answer for further explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also write like this

```
@for $i from 1 through 100 {
  .t-#{$i} {
    top: #{$i + '%'};
  }
}
```